# Which is the charset for characters ╠ü ╠é?

Tags: android, pdf, character-encoding

When i save a pdf file in my android from my application.
I use Zip4J Library to unzip the file that i download, and then, save the pdf file in android folder.
The pdf files that have accents (special characters) appears like:

```
é = ╠ü
â = ╠é
```

and so on.

You know what is the charset of these files and why are they been saved like this?

Comment: It seems you aren't saving as UTF-8 Unicode.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. But why? Im just downloading a file, unzipping and saving the file in a folder.

Comment: It appears that you are saving the data (possibly, byte by byte) in a different codepage

Answer (score 2):

Looks like UTF-8 octets displayed as [DOS code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850):

- `╠` is `0xcc` in cp850
- `ü` is `0x81` in cp850
- UTF-8 octets `cc 81` are [combining acute accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm) and if preceded by `e`, it will make it `é`

Similarly the `╠é` makes up to a [combining circumflex accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm).

So the data seems to be saved all right as UTF-8. You are just displaying it incorrectly.

Comment: A combining acute accent *preceded* by “e” makes “é” (for a certain value for “makes”, namely “is a decomposed character that is canonical equivalent to”).